# How to verify whether an address variable points to an existing account?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, addresses, address.transfer

```
function pay(address payee, uint value) public {
    // How to ensure that payee is an existing account?
    payee.transfer(value);
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way. Any valid address is liable to receive payments. There is no concept of existing account.

If anyone has the valid private key of `payee` address, he can unlock the account and spend funds else the funds are freeze and can not be accessed.